# How do I fix “This iPhone was not able to download 8 full-resolution photos and videos.” when trying to disable iCloud on my phone

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I ran out of iCloud storage a very long time ago but didn't think anything of it since I was using Google Photos. The problem is that for some reason the ‘optimise iPhone storage’ option was checked and it seems like I can't recover some of my photos.

Initially it had this error message with thousands of photos, but I managed to downloaded them by selecting a bunch and then going ‘share’ then ‘email’ which downloaded them onto my device... there's one photo that is flagged up as being unrecoverable that I've managed to download via iCloud web, but I cannot find the other 7 or see which ones they are, and the thought of potentially losing 7 random photos of my son really sucks.

Is there anyway to recover them please? Or at the very least see which 7 photos haven't downloaded in full resolution? Thank you